# Error when trying to bring up the network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I run the command `./byfn.sh -m generate` everything is fine.

I am trying to bring up the network using the command

```
./byfn.sh -m up
```

But I get an error:

```
2018-03-28 08:47:19.896 UTC [main] main -> INFO 001 Exiting.....
LOCAL_VERSION=1.1.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0
orderer.example.com is up-to-date
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ...
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ...
Creating peer1.org1.example.com ... error
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ...
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ... error
ERROR: for peer1.org1.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer1.org                                                                                                                                  1.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  nis not a valid Windows path'

ERROR: for peer1.org2.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer1.org                                                                                                                                  2.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... error

Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... error
1.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  nis not a valid Windows path'

ERROR: for peer0.org2.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org                                                                                                                                  2.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  nis not a valid Windows path'

ERROR: for peer1.org1.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer1.org                                                                                                                                  1.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  nis not a valid Windows path'

ERROR: for peer1.org2.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer1.org                                                                                                                                  2.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  nis not a valid Windows path'

ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org                                                                                                                                  1.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  nis not a valid Windows path'

ERROR: for peer0.org2.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org                                                                                                                                  2.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\var\\\\run:/host/var/run/"\                                                                                                                                  nis not a valid Windows path'
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
```

I tried to resolve it and I think there is something wrong with docker.Especially after I updated it.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b2
```

I re-installed docker but now I get the error below:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had the same problem.
If you've have this issue at Windows, try this.
open **.env** file in **fabric-samples/first-network/** 
and add this
**COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1**

Comment: I did something and now I get different error can you please see the picture

Comment: It seems that you don't have hyperledger/fabric images 
You can get these images to try  "curl -sSL https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0"

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with steps below:

```
$ cd [to your working folder of Fabric]
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
$ cd fabric-examples/
$ export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
$ cd first-network
$ vi .env 
--and add COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

$ ./byfn.sh -m generate
$ ./byfn.sh -m up
```

Special thanks to 권하경